# Some HTML tags are not displaying in body(ckeditor) of content type

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to put HTML file content into a body part of a content type.

**Procedure:** When user uploads a zip file I will extract and replace `<img src="path"` with different path and put that replaced content into body of the content type. This will be done in `hook_node_presave()`.

**Code:**

```
               if(trim($unzipped_filename) == 'index.html') {
                    $renamed_filename = $unzipped_path . '/testing.html';
                    //rename the index.html
                    $renaming_index = rename($unzipped_files[0],$renamed_filename);

                    //open file and get data
                    $htmldata = file_get_contents($renamed_filename); 
                    //Match all img src tags from html file        
                    preg_match_all('/<img\s.*?\bsrc="(.*?)".*?>/si', $htmldata, $matches);
                    $i = '';
                    $replacewith = array();
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
                     //Store replacing strings in an array
                      $replacewith[] = base_path() . $unzipped_path . $matches[1][$i];
                    }     
                    //Replace all img src tags from html file                 
                    $replacedhtml = str_replace($matches[1], $replacewith, $htmldata);

                    file_put_contents($unzipped_path . 'renamed.html', $replacedhtml);
                    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $replacedhtml;

                  }
```

In the above code `$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $replacedhtml;` like this I am placing replaced content of HTMl into body part.

**Problem:** In database I can see all the Tags: etc. But in content its not displaying these tags. Because of this, its not taking JS and css files to load the content. Below html content is not displaying in body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEXT Example</title>
<link href="css/Academy-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>
```

So where I am going wrong please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your configured input format settings. It is likely the input format or a specific filter are stripping HTML tags out.

Answer (score 0):

As Vincent said, its a logic of configuration part of CkEditor.

`Advanced Content Filter` was stripping these tags.

Hope it helps somebody..